# Python: Loop Parameters

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, counter, integer-division

I apologize if I haven't titled this appropriately, but I'm having trouble getting the following code to execute. The for loop parameters seem to be at least part of the problem. If I substitute "limit" for "num" in the for loop to yield "for j in range(1, limit)", the loop executes and gives the desired output. But with num instead of limit, I should be able to more precisely control iterations of the loop but it will not complete yet does not present an error.

```
from collections import Counter

limit = int(input('What number do you want to factor?'))
num = limit
factors = []
while num != 1:
    for j in range(2, num):        
        if (num % j == 0):
            num = num // j
            factors.append(j)
            break

factorEnum = Counter(factors)

print(factors)
print(factorEnum)
```

The purpose of the code is to produce prime factorization of a given number. For example for the number 28, the prime factors are  {2, 7} but I'm looking for prime factorization which would be {2, 2, 7}. This code is part of another script that looks for the least common multiple of a range of numbers (1 - 40 for example.) This is a problem from ProjectEuler.

Comment: `if (num % j == 0):` when that isn't True, you don't change `num` so your loop runs forever. And suppose `num` was 2, then `for j in range(2, num)` doesn't run, num is not decreased and the same thing happens.

Comment: Add a few prints and you'll see where it goes wrong. Better yet, run it in the `pdb3` debugger.

Comment: @tdelaney That would only be true if at some point the value of 'j' weren't equal to 'num'. Even if the number were prime, it would still loop through until 'j == num' and 'num' would be set to 'num' // 'j' which would be 1. Then the break statement exits the for loop and the value of 'num' being 1 exits the while loop. ... I think.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. But I don't think the value of the second parameter really matters as even if it is set to 'limit' it will never execute past the value of 'num' anyway. But I'm still interested in knowing why this isn't working.

Comment: `range` doesn't include the endpoint so j will never equal num. I added a print and ran your code with 15. It spun on 5 forever.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok.. So if the user entered a prime number for example it would loop forever?

Comment: It loops forever for all numbers. If the number is a multiple of 2, it loops because you eventually hit `range(2,2)` which doesn't produce any numbers. Otherwise, it loops when the number reduces to a prime. If I enter `8` or `16` etc... it has the 2 problem. If I enter, say, `42`, that loops when it finally reaches `7`.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments by tdelaney above. This pretty much solved my problem.

Since the 'range' function doesn't include the endpoint the for loop never exits. This is true for any number. But using 'limit' extends the range of the for loop beyond the value of 'num' for all numbers except prime numbers. So 'limit' works unless the number is prime.

I changed the code to 'num + 1' as the second parameter and that worked fine.

Thanks @tdelaney.